# How to create a sorting function that takes as parameter the method in which it should be sorted

Tags: java, list, sorting, lambda, comparator

I have a List of entities, and I want to be able to sort the List using a custom .sort() function which takes as parameter the way the list should be sorted.
e.g.

```
repo.sort(sort by field) 
repo.sort(sort by field but ascending) 
repo.sort(sort by field descending and by another field ascending)
```

My train of thought was that i should make a sort function that gets overloaded and depending on the number of parameters it should behave a certain way, but i feel that i am overcomplicating it
and was wondering if there is a simpler way.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Using  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#sort-java.util.Comparator- with a custom Comparator.

Comment: `persons.sort(Comparator.comparing(Person::getName).thenComparingInt(Person::getAge().reversed());` as a small example showcasing everything you mentioned.

Answer (score -1):

Comparator is an interface and as such it has to have unified method definitions.  There are a couple of ways to handle what you want, but not by parameter in the predefined method signatures:

1. Create several custom `Comparator`, one for each field(s) to use.
2. Create a single `Comparator` with predefined settings and you add a setter method to have it use those configurations.

I would add that you should NOT write a `Comparator` to handle reverse ordering.  Use the methods available to you through the `Collections` utility, namley `Collections.reverse()`

Comment: This mimicks to great extent functionality provided by static methods in `Comparator`. Also `Collections.reverse()` will reverse the collection, not the ordering from a comparator(by particular field in this exact case). This method is not applicable when working with comparators.